# How to prevent the need login everytime without logout in Ionic App?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

How I can make my Ionic App to prevent the need login everytime after exit app or back to background without logout ?
Its my source code:

**login.js**

```
   angular.module('starter.controllers')

   .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$localStorage', '$q', '$http', '$window', '$state', 'AuthFac tory', 'SessionFactory',
       function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $localStorage, $q, $http, $window, $cordovaSQLite, $state, AuthFactory, SessionFactory) {

           $scope.login = {
               email: null,
               password: null
           };

           $scope.login = function() {
               $rootScope.showLoading("Authenticating..");

               var email = $scope.login.email,
                   password = $scope.login.password;

               if (email !== undefined && password !== undefined) {
                   AuthFactory.login(email, password).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                       if (data.success === false) {
                           $rootScope.hideLoading();
                           $rootScope.toast('Invalid Credentials');
                       } else {
                           SessionFactory.isLogged = true;
                           SessionFactory.user = data.data.username;
                           SessionFactory.userRole = data.data.name;
                           $localStorage.id = data.data.id;
                           $localStorage.token = data.data.token;
                           $window.sessionStorage.token = data.data.token;
                           console.log($window.sessionStorage.token);
                           $localStorage.user = data.data.username; // to fetch the user details on refresh
                           console.log($localStorage.user);
                           $localStorage.userRole = data.data.name; // to fetch the user details on refresh
                           console.log($localStorage.userRole);
                       } //end else data.success
                   }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                       if (status === 500) {
                           $rootScope.hideLoading();
                           $rootScope.toast('Invalid Email');
                       }
                   });
               }
           };
       }
   ]);
```

**authfactory.js**

```
angular.module('starter.factories')

.factory('SessionFactory', function($window, $localStorage) {
  var auth = {
    isLogged: false,
    check: function() {
      if ($localStorage.token && $localStorage.user ) {
        this.isLogged = true;
      } else {
        this.isLogged = false;
        delete this.user;
      }
    }
  }


  return auth;
})


    .factory('AuthFactory', function($window, $location, $http, SessionFactory, $localStorage) {
      return {
        login: function(email, password) {
          return $http.post('url', {
            email : email,
            password: password
          });

        },

        logout: function() {

          if (SessionFactory.isLogged) {

            SessionFactory.isLogged = false;
            delete SessionFactory.user;
            delete SessionFactory.userRole;

            delete $localStorage.token;
            delete $localStorage.user ;
            delete $window.sessionStorage.userRole;

            $location.path("/login");
          }

        }
      }
    })


    .factory('TokenInterceptor', function($q, $window, $localStorage) {
      return {
        request: function(config) {
          config.headers = config.headers || {};
          if ($localStorage.token) {
            config.headers['X-Access-Token'] = $localStorage.token;
            config.headers['X-Key'] = $localStorage.user;
            config.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json";
          }
          return config || $q.when(config);
        },

        response: function(response) {
          return response || $q.when(response);
        }
      };
    })
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', []);
angular.module('starter.services', []);
angular.module('starter.factories', []);

angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'starter.factories', 'ngCordova', 'ngRoute'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $ionicLoading, $state, $location, $q, $http, $timeout, $localStorage, $window, SessionFactory) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }

    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(event) {
      if ($state.current.name == "tab.dashboard") {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
        console.log('1');
      } else {
        navigator.app.backHistory();
        console.log('2');
      }
    }, 100);

    if (window.cordova) {


    });

    // when the page refreshes, check if the user is already logged in
    SessionFactory.check(); $rootScope.showLoading = function(msg) {
      $ionicLoading.show({
        template: msg || 'Loading',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
      });
      $timeout(function() {
        $rootScope.hideLoading();
      }, 2999);
    }

    $rootScope.hideLoading = function() {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    };

    $rootScope.toast = function(msg) {
      $rootScope.showLoading(msg);
      $timeout(function() {
        $rootScope.hideLoading();
      }, 2999);
    };

    $ionicPlatform.on('resume', function() {
      $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, nextRoute, currentRoute) {
        if ((nextRoute.access && nextRoute.access.requiredLogin) && !SessionFactory.isLogged) {
          $location.path("/login");
        } else {
          // check if user object exists else fetch it. This is incase of a page refresh
          if (!SessionFactory.user) SessionFactory.user = $localStorage.user;
          if (!SessionFactory.userRole) SessionFactory.userRole = $localStorage.userRole;
        }
        console.log('true');
      });

      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, nextRoute, currentRoute) {
        $rootScope.showMenu = SessionFactory.isLogged;
        $rootScope.role = SessionFactory.userRole;
        // if the user is already logged in, take him to the home page
        if (SessionFactory.isLogged == true && $location.path() == '/login') {
          $location.path('/tab/price');
        }
      });
      console.log(SessionFactory.isLogged);
      $rootScope.$broadcast('onResume');
    });

    $ionicPlatform.on('pause', function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('onPause');
      console.log('pause');
    });


  })

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
    // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
    // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
    // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
    $stateProvider

    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl',
      access: {
        requiredLogin: false
      }
    })


    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

  });
```

**login.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Ionic App">
  <ion-content> 
    <ion-list>
      <form name="loginForm">
        <div class="list">

            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="login.email"  required>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                 <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="login.password"  required>
            </label>
              <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="login()" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">
           <b>Login</b>
           </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I hope anyone can help me to solve this problem

Comment: Why not add a plunker instead of adding so much code ??

Answer (score 2):

A Simple and recommended solution : Store user credentials in localStorage and perform auto login. As i see your code, you are already storing some user details in the localStorage. You can check if those details exist in the localStorage when your controller loads and call your login method directly.

Something like this :

```
function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $localStorage, $q, $http, $window, $cordovaSQLite, $state, AuthFactory, SessionFactory) {
   $scope.login = {
       email: null,
       password: null
   };

   $scope.isLoggedIn = false;

   $scope.login = function() {

        // on login set a flag to mark the user as logged in

   };


   if (!$scope.isLoggedIn) {   
        if ($localStorage.userName  !== undefined and $localStorage.password !== undefined) {
            $scope.login();
        }
   }

]);
```

Alternatively, if you're working on some login token driven authentication, you can also store that token and use it for communicating with the server next time.

Don't forget to use encryption though (y)

Comment: Thanks but after open again this app not automatically redirect to /#/home but just to /login location for identification first time. How I can fix it so redirect with automatically to /#/home without to /login location again?

Comment: You can show some splash screen when you app launches, check if username / password are already stored, if stored then login directly else open the login screen instead.

Comment: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $localStorageProvider <- $localStorage <- login

Answer (score 0):

1). In $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(''), set the url of your app's dashboard or main page where user is sent after login. Lets suppose $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard').

2). In dashboard's controller, inject the service which checks for user authentication and send the user to login if not authenticated.

Comment: How about elaborate with  $rootScope.$on feature?

Answer (score 0):

It Is Possible By using Local storage In Ionic

1. Set some credentials in local storage when you logins first time
   `window.localStorage.setItem("username", "rahul");
    window.localStorage.setItem("password", "123");`
2. Check Local storage for credentials when you opens your app next time in .run() method.

   ```
       var localval = window.localStorage.getItem('username');
       var localval1 = window.localStorage.getItem('password');
       console.log(localval);
       if(localval != null && localval1 != null)
       {
         $state.go('app.home');
       }
   ```
3. Clear apps local storage when you logout from app
   `window.localStorage.removeItem("username", "rahul");
   window.localStorage.removeItem("password", "123");`